# How to get the Wordpress thumbnail image with mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I can get the _thumbnail_id but not the actual image from the Wordpress database. How can I extract the thumbnail image url? Do I need an "inner join"?

This is what I have:

```
SELECT Y31f6z2_posts.ID,
       Y31f6z2_posts.post_title as title,
       Y31f6z2_posts.post_type,
       property_thumb.meta_value as thumb,
       property_price.meta_value as price
FROM   Y31f6z2_posts
LEFT JOIN Y31f6z2_postmeta as property_thumb on (Y31f6z2_posts.ID = property_thumb.post_id AND property_thumb.meta_key='_thumbnail_id')
LEFT JOIN Y31f6z2_postmeta as property_price on (Y31f6z2_posts.ID = property_price.post_id AND property_price.meta_key='property_price')
WHERE  Y31f6z2_posts.post_type = 'property' limit 3;
```

This gives the result:

```
ID        title        post_type     thumb     price
426737    Two bedroom  property      426738    399990
426756    Two bedroom  property      426757    74950
426758    Spacious th  property      426759    74950
```

But I need the actual thumbnail image which is the result of the "select" statement below. (ID = value of "thumb")

```
    mysql> select guid from Y31f6z2_posts where ID = '426738';
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| guid                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| path-to-image/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/000855-01.jpg |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Many thanks,

Neil.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Question is still unclear and incomplete after the edit and seams that magicly getting data from unknown sources.. Be sure to read the above link very clear.. ->  Also read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section *"Proof-read before posting!"* -> *"Read through the Question from start to finish. Pretend you're seeing it for the first time: does it make sense? Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question"*

Comment: With *"Try reproducing the problem yourself, in a fresh environment and make sure you can do so using only the information included in your question"* ->  we mean can it complete run (error free in this case) on a [fresh environment](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k7hsRLh4kD9tjkkt7UNfA9/0)

Comment: I need the result of a query run on the output of the first left join.